# nodester node version error

Tags: node.js, npm, nodester

Every time I try to install a module or list the installed modules with `nodester npm`, I end up with this.

```
nodester Error: npm doesn't work with node v0.8.1
nodester Required: node@0.4 || 0.5 || 0.6
nodester     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:57:23
nodester     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:77:
3)
nodester     at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
nodester     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
nodester     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
nodester     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
nodester     at Module.runMain (module.js:487:10)
nodester     at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:2
```

Does anyone know what this message actually means? I can't seem to find any information on it.
It's talking about the version of npm on the nodester server judging by the path (I'm on Windows).

Comment: I've got this problem to! Can it be that nodester don't use the newest version?

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this problem on my Ubuntu setup and basically I updated NPM and it resolved the issue.  For me it appears I needed to configure NPM to work with the current version of node installed.  Hope this helps somebody else who stumbles across this post as I struggled to find an answer any where.